# Как в запросе получить нумерацию, чтобы все повторяющиеся позиции нумеровалась одинаково?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Как получить такую нумерацию строк, как в столбце `necessary result`?

Надо, чтобы все повторяющиеся позиции, нумеровалась одинаково.

```
WITH IDLE AS (
SELECT '1' AS ID, 'OTHER' AS idle, '1' AS "necessary result" FROM dual union all
SELECT '2',       'ППР',           '2'                       FROM dual union all
SELECT '3',       'OTHER',         '3'                       FROM dual union all
SELECT '4',       'ППР',           '4'                       FROM dual union all
SELECT '5',       'ППР',           '4'                       FROM dual union all
SELECT '6',       'OTHER',         '5'                       FROM dual union all
SELECT '7',       'ППР',           '6'                       FROM dual union all
SELECT '8',       'ППР',           '6'                       FROM dual union all
SELECT '9',       'ППР',           '6'                       FROM dual union all
SELECT '10',      'OTHER',         '7'                       FROM dual 
)
SELECT IDLE.*  FROM IDLE
```

Comment: А как у вас данные в реальной таблице сортируются? Почему у `id='10'` желаемый результат '7', а не '1' ?

Comment: Коллеги в очереди на закрытие, вопрос не "домашка", нетривиален и вполне качественный. Воздержитесь пожалуйста от голоса за закрытие.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Посчитайте накапливающуюся сумму (т.н. *running total*) только по изменениям в столбце `IDLE`.
В этом поможет конструкция `sum(...) over (order by ...)`, вот так:

```sql
with idle as (
    select '1' as id, 'OTHER' as idle, '1' as necessary_result   from dual union all
    select '2',       'ППР',           '2'                       from dual union all
    select '3',       'OTHER',         '3'                       from dual union all
    select '4',       'ППР',           '4'                       from dual union all
    select '5',       'ППР',           '4'                       from dual union all
    select '6',       'OTHER',         '5'                       from dual union all
    select '7',       'ППР',           '6'                       from dual union all
    select '8',       'ППР',           '6'                       from dual union all
    select '9',       'ППР',           '6'                       from dual union all
    select '10',      'OTHER',         '7'                       from dual 
)
select q2.id, idle, necessary_result, to_char (sum (chng) over (order by num)) result
from (
    select q1.*, case when prev = idle then 0 else 1 end chng 
    from (
        select idle.*, to_number (id) num, lag (idle) over (order by to_number (id)) prev 
        from idle
    ) q1
) q2    
order by num;
```

Выведет:

```
ID IDLE   necessary_result result          
-- ------ ---------------- ----------------
1  OTHER  1                1               
2  ППР    2                2               
3  OTHER  3                3               
4  ППР    4                4               
5  ППР    4                4               
6  OTHER  5                5               
7  ППР    6                6               
8  ППР    6                6               
9  ППР    6                6               
10 OTHER  7                7
```

Comment: Гениально, спасибо большое!

Comment: @Wilson Рад был помочь! Так как вы не ответили на комментарий под вопросом, то думаю сами разобрались. Если `ID` численный тип, не забудте заменить `to_number (id)` на `id`.

Comment: Для меня важна идея, а остальное сам уже доработаю. Все поля с числами, имеют  числовой формат, что учту в следующий раз и буду писать без кавычек. А работа агрегатной функции SUM() в аналитическом  контексте необычна, я предполагал, она должна  отдавать значение, равное входному.